# Vue.js Tracking.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, tracking.js

I'm trying to make use of the tracking.js library in my vueJS application.

I've installed the package like so.

```
npm install --save tracking
```

I'm then defining the library in my main.js file

```
import tracking from 'tracking'
Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$tracking', { value: tracking });
```

Then in my component i'm trying to use the library like so

```
mounted() {
  var tracker = new this.$tracking.ObjectTracker('webcam');
}
```

I feel I am calling the library wrong but the error message is

> TypeError: this.$tracking.ObjectTracker is not a constructor

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the import statement, it seems that trackingjs does not support ES6 import. You have to have it in a sort of global scope

```
Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$tracking', { value: tracking });


new Vue({
  created: function() {
   var tracker = new this.$tracking.Tracker()
  console.log(tracker)
  }
})
```

Here [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/ucw31m5x/2/) work as expected. Notice it's added only like a dependecy. i.e `<script src="path/to/trackingjs">`